# OWIN Webapi app receiving "System.ArgumentException no conversion available..." when bundled with nuget

Tags: c#, owin, katana

I'm attempting to setup a self-hosted OWin app (using VS2012) - I think it's close since
I can run OwinHost.exe from the directory containing the .csproj and application serves from localhost:5000 correctly. I created a default nuspec file and added the following

```
<files>
  <file src="bin\*.dll" target="bin" />
  <file src="views\home\home.html" target="content" />
  <file src="web.config" target="content" />
</files>
```

in AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(TestA.Startup))]
```

When I install the package ( nuget install mypackage ) I get the following error...

Starting with the default port: 5000...

```
Error:  System.ArgumentException
No conversion available between 
System.Func`2[System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object],
System.Threading.Tasks.Task] and Microsoft.Owin.OwinMiddleware. 
Parameter name: signature
```

Let me know if you would like more info

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go into `Manage Nuget Packages for Solution...` on the solution, choose `Updates` and click `Update All` (or select the owin related ones as applicable).

This fixed it for me.

**Original Error:**

> Error:  System.ArgumentException   No conversion available between
>   System.Func`2[System.Collections.Generic.IDict
>   ionary`2[System.String,System.Object],System.Threading.Tasks.Task] and
>   Microsoft .Owin.OwinMiddleware. Parameter name: signature

**After Updating Nuget Packages:**

> Starting with the default port: 5000 (http://localhost:5000/) Started
>   successfully Press Enter to exit

Comment: For anyone that still has the problem, take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31675238/205859

Comment: updated all installed "Owin" related NuGet packages to the current version (as of today: v3.1.0) seems to have worked for me. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score -1):

Solved with some old school beyond comparing - folder structure was incorrect, I set nuspec targets for views/* and web.config under "content" instead of "" - now all works.

Comment: What is a nuspec target?

Comment: after 1.5 years if I had to guess I would say a target attribute value in the nuspec file. @Coulton 's answer is more up to date