# No conversion available between HelloWorldComponent and System.Func`2[System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2 // Parameter name: signature

Tags: owin, katana, owin-middleware

I am working through Scott Allen's MVC 5 Fundamentals course on Pluralsight

I get an error at "using (WebApp.Start(uri)) " in the code below.

The error is

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Microsoft.Owin.dll
  System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=No conversion available between ConsoleApplication1.HelloWorldComponent and System.Func`2[System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object],System.Threading.Tasks.Task].
Parameter name: signature
  Source=Microsoft.Owin
  ParamName=signature
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Owin.Builder.AppBuilder.Convert(Type signature, Object app)
       at Microsoft.Owin.Builder.AppBuilder.BuildInternal(Type signature)
       at Microsoft.Owin.Builder.AppBuilder.Build(Type returnType)
       at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.ServerFactory.ServerFactoryAdapter.Create(IAppBuilder builder)
       at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine.StartServer(StartContext context)
       at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine.Start(StartContext context)
       at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Starter.DirectHostingStarter.Start(StartOptions options)
       at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Starter.HostingStarter.Start(StartOptions options)
       at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.StartImplementation(IServiceProvider services, StartOptions options)
       at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start(StartOptions options)
       at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start[TStartup](StartOptions options)
       at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start[TStartup](String url)
       at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in e:\EShared\Dev2015\WebAppScottAllen\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 16
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

The code is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
using Owin;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using AppFunc = Func<IDictionary<string, object>, Task>;
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string uri = "http://localhost:8080";
            using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(uri))   // Katana Please start, using the configuration from the Startup class and listening on the port given by the uri
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Started!");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.WriteLine("Stopping!");
            }
        }
    }

    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.Use<HelloWorldComponent>();
        }
    }

    public class HelloWorldComponent
    {
        AppFunc _next;
        public HelloWorldComponent(AppFunc next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        // Katana uses reflection to find this Invoke function that matches the AppFunc signature
        public Task Invoke(IDictionary<string, object> environment)
        { 
            var response = environment["owin.ResponseBody"] as Stream;

            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(response))
            {
                return writer.WriteAsync("Hello");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

packages.config is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Diagnostics" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Hosting" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
</packages>
```

I wonder did not use to get this message, so I wonder what could have changed

Comment: I see some information https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/242

Comment: Also https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/2116  talks about adding binding redirects however mine look like the example

Comment: The code looks 100% correct and I can paste it into a new project and watch it work. Interesting. I don't have any assembly redirects in app.config, though, perhaps you can comment them out and see how it behaves?

Comment: No difference commenting out the redirects. If I create a new project from scratch I have the same problem.  I have tried .net frameworks 4.5 and 4.5.1

Comment: Odd, feel free to .zip the project and send it along, I'll take a closer look. Email address here: http://odetocode.com/about/contact

Comment: Thanks Scott, I sent you the email.

Comment: Ah, the code in the project you send has an Invoke function with an extra Task parameter at the end. Remove that, and all should be good.

Comment: Ah, thanks Scott, I wonder how on earth I did that!

Comment: I am getting same issue while following this course. But can't figure out how this issue was resolved here.

Comment: @Manoj the code above was right at the time, it was a dyslexic mistake on my part that Scott found when I sent him the Zip.  Checkout Ufuk-Hacıoğulları  's answer below.

Comment: oh.. ok Thanks @kirsten

Answer (score 4):

There is a new way to write our middlewares components, which looks like this:

```
public class HelloWorldComponent : OwinMiddleware
{
    public HelloWorldComponent(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next) { }

    public override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        return context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

Specifically, **the constructor must accept an `OwinMiddleware` reference** as its first parameter, otherwise you get an error because the ctor signature does not match what is expected by the current Owin implementation.

Further, consider the following **parameterized usage**:

```
    var param1 = "Hello, World!";
    appBuilder.Use<HelloWorldComponent>(param1)
```

To properly support this you will want a modified constructor signature:

```
public class HelloWorldComponent : OwinMiddleware
{
    public HelloWorldComponent(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next) { }

    public override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context, string param1)
    {
        return context.Response.WriteAsync(param1);
    }
}
```

Thus, allowing us to parameterize our middleware via `Use()`'s params array.

Comment: you sure you've got that right? How can you override a method with a custom parameter? Wouldn't OwinMiddleware base have to supply a ridiculous amount of overloads to permit that?

Comment: @Quibblesome I think it was an overload with params object[], so it's not safely typed.

Answer (score 0):

Inheriting from `OwinMiddleware` limits you to the Katana implementation of OWIN.
Creating a `OwinContext` from the passed `environment` should work for you

```
class HelloWorldComponent 
    {
        private readonly AppFunc _next;

        public HelloWorldComponent (AppFunc next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(IDictionary<string, object> environment)
        {

            var ctx = new OwinContext(environment);
            await ctx.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World");
            await _next(environment);
        }
    }
```